# Show current DateTime as a Survey question

Tags: date-time, survey-list

I have a survey list with some questions. I want each survey to have current DateTime.

I used DateTime column and set the default value as Today's Date but when i try to respond to survey the column shows incorrect Time.

I have checked all the regional setting and everything seems to be correct.

**Regional Settings at Site Collection Level.**

[image]

**My Regional Settings**

[image]

The date that can be seen in the survey is as below:

[image]

Please help me understand why is the Current Date is incorrect in the survey form.

Comment: Can you clarify what "incorrect Time" means in this case?

Comment: @RobertLindgren check last screenshot showing system datetim and date in sharepoint form.

Answer (score 0):

Set the list column date output type to be Calculated with a value of "=NOW()", that should do the trick.

Comment: Now() shows time related to server i guess. Is it? Because when i used it i got result as, time from France with 1 hour difference exact. Still doesnt solve my issue. I want to know why is Todays date in DateTime not working properly.

Comment: It rounds to the nearest hour I understand. It seems a bit overkill tbh as the date and time that the item shows is for an event, and presumably they can't go on the event at that precise moment in time anyway.

Comment: Not sure. When actual time is 8:13 PM in Paris it shows as 7:13 PM. Also i have my regional settings set as IST and the time shown is close to CET where the server exist.